# Python Script Error - try except inside a for loop - Syntax Error

Tags: python-2.7, scripting, aws-lambda

I am trying to call a function using the below mentioned "*python script*" in ("*AWS Lambda*") while executing I am getting a error in one of the line containing "*for loop: try & except*"

The Script is used to create a AMI of existing aws instances

> ParseError: bad input on line 48

Line 48 says:

```
43 for instance in instances:
44        try:
46            retention_days = [
47                int(t.get('Value')) for t in instance['Tags']
48                if t['Key'] == 'Retention'][0]
49          except IndexError:
50                retention_days = 7
```

I try to add "**finally:**" to close the try: as below

```
43.    for instance in instances:
44.        try:
45.            retention_days = [
46.                int(t.get('Value')) for t in instance['Tags']
47.                if t['Key'] == 'Retention'][0]
48.             finally:
49.               retention_days.close()
50.        except IndexError:
51.            retention_days = 7
```

But still I am getting the same error, as I am new to python I am not sure how to overcome this exception.

The full script is available at [GitHub-AMI-Creation-Script](https://gist.github.com/bkozora/724e01903a9ad481d21e)

Answer (score 0):

The `finally` clause in your code is in the wrong place.  It should be at the same indentation level as `try` and `except`, e.g.:

```
try:
    <some code>
except IndexError:
    <some code>
finally:
    <some code>
```

The code in the `finally` clause will always be executed regardless of whether there is an exception or not.  This is often used to clean up or free up resources.

Comment: @gamaat: Thanks for correcting me, let me try with the below changes to the code: **'for instance in instances:
       try:
           retention_days = [
               int(t.get('Value')) for t in instance['Tags']
               if t['Key'] == 'Retention'][0]
       except IndexError:
           retention_days = 7
    finally:
              retention_days.close()'**

Not sure the finally close call I used is correct

Answer (score 0):

Your code inside the try is rather confusing, it doesn't really seem to read correctly.

You are parsing t.get('Value') to int but haven't created t yet as you do that on the same line and your for t in instance['Tags'] is missing an end ':'

I haven't tested this and feel free to change it or play with it but this might help towards your aim:

```
 for instance in instances:
     try:
         for t in instance['Tags']:
             if t['Key'] == 'Retention':
                 retention_days = int(t['Value'])
     except IndexError:
         retention_days = 7
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for answering my queries, I tried testing with your given change but its throwing a syntax error again: **'Syntax error in module 'lambda_function': unindent does not match any outer indentation level** (lambda_function.py, line 48)'

Comment: If you copied and pasted my code directly, I didn't get the indents perfectly the same for each line so you may just need to go through and check the indents are all the same. Python is quite specific about indentation which is what that error message is about.

Comment: @Subash I've fixed the indents in my snippet, can you try now?